# express-validator extracting validation into separate file

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I am trying to validate some input using express validator but i have a different setup than one in the documentation.

Im validating if the body.payload is not null

this.validator.document

```
   public document = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        check("payload").exists({ checkNull: true });
        try {
            validationResult(req).throw();
            next();
          } catch (err) {
            res.status(422).json({ errors: err.mapped() });
        }
    }
```

this.controller.document

```
 public document = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<any> => {

        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
          return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
       }
}
```

documentRoute

```
     this.router.post("/:id/document",
            this.jwtGuard,
            this.validator.document,
            this.controller.document);
```

im aware check is a middleware in itself, so how do i handle this inside my existing validator function that may have some other validation before it.

At the moment this does not work, even tho payload is set to null. It should catch the error and return a 422 response but it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `validator.document`:

```
public document = () => check("payload").exists({ checkNull: true });
```

in `documentRoute`:

```
this.router.post("/:id/document",
        this.jwtGuard,
        this.validator.document(), // notice the parentheses
        this.controller.document);
```

**Update**: If you want to handle the errors in `validator.document`, you need to call `check` middleware before it when declaring the route:

```
this.router.post("/:id/document",
    this.jwtGuard,
    check("payload").exists({ checkNull: true }),
    this.validator.document,
    this.controller.document);
```

And in `validator.document`:

```
public document = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
   const errors = validationResult(req);
   if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
   }
}
```

**Update 2**: If you have multiple check operations and does not want to bloat your route definition, I suggest you use [schema validation](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/schema-validation.html).

Comment: right i think my route would get very long doing it this way (i could be checking for multiple things). I was hoping to combine the check middleware and the validator.document middleware into a single function.

Comment: I guess i could make validator.document into a generic catch validation function and put all the checks inside of validator.document

Comment: Yes, you can also use schema validation

Comment: if the document function is a middleware why do we need to add the parenthesis ()

Comment: because the `check` function is not per say a _middleware_, it is a function that _returns_ a middleware.